# How to delete an address, phone, email, or website in a profile?

Tags: profile, addresses

I've created a CiviCRM profile with address fields, and with email, phone, and website fields, and configured this profile for use in the Drupal Account Edit screen.  Some users may want to delete these fields from their profile, but this doesn't seem to be possible. When the user deletes the values of all the address fields, and/or deletes the phone, email, or website form values, and saves the form, the existing field values remain untouched.

As a very poor workaround, the user can enter a bogus value like '-' for the phone number, or for address fields, but email and website require valid formats, so even this poor workaround fails for those fields.

Is there a way to allow deleting on these entities in a profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall this coming up a number of times on the old Forum and the answer was 'can't be done'. And I thought this was going to be an unhelpful answer but [Post 1](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35754.0) took me to [Post 2](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-10551) which took me to this [Include ID when editing 'block' fields (+ allow deletion of block values via Profiles)](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16877) which is flagged as Fixed for 4.7.

What version are you on? Want to go test on [master](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/welcome?destination=node/1)

Comment: Yep, I'm on 4.6. Just tested on 4.7 (just an old 4.7.3 dev site I have lying around), and simply deleting does indeed make the block entities go away. Thanks, Pete!